# PCM Audio file and volume

Tags: audio, pcm

I'm working with raw pcm files(with no headers) and I was wondering, does anyone know the calculation to find the current volume of a section of sound? I have all the information on the file, such as the sample rate, channels, bits per sample, etc. I figure there must be some type of equation.